# habilitar o deshabilitar input si tiene datos o no

Tags: php, javascript

una pregunta ya he buscado algo de información pero no me satisface, tengo un formulario en un modal y muestra un input text con un curp, esto lo hago para poder modificarlo, lo que quiero hacer es que si ya trae datos, sea de solo lectura, si lo muestra vacio, que me deje escribir para actualizar el registro...

Saludos

---

```
<!-- Edit Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" 
  data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog ">
            <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #000000; ">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #ffffff">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="color: #ffffff">Actualizar Datos</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="update.php" method="POST">
                                        <div class="container-fluid">
                                                <div class="form-group input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Curp:</span>
                                                    <input type="hidden" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="eid_generales" id="eid_generales">
                                                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="ecurp" id="ecurp">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Paterno:</span>
                                                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="epaterno" id="epaterno">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Materno:</span>
                                                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="ematerno" id="ematerno">
                                                </div>                  
                                                <div class="form-group input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Nombre:</span>
                                                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="enombre" id="enombre">
                                                </div>
                                        </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <input type="image" name=""  style="border: none;" src="images/edit.png" title="Actualizar!">
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /.modal -->


este es mi modal....   solo busco que si hay curp, se haga de solo lectura y si no, que me permita capturar el dato

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6NC3.png
```

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){

```
    var id=$(this).val();
    var curp = $('#curp'+id).text();
    var paterno=$('#paterno'+id).text();
    var materno=$('#materno'+id).text();
    var nombre=$('#nombre'+id).text();

    $('#edit').modal('show');
    $('#eid_generales').val(id);
    $('#ecurp').val(curp);
    $('#epaterno').val(paterno);
    $('#ematerno').val(materno);
    $('#enombre').val(nombre);
});
```

});

este es el js con el que envio los datos al input

Comment: Debes incluir código que hiciste para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que escribiste como Respuesta, en tu misma pregunta.

Comment: vale gracias es la primera vez que pregunto...

Answer (score 1):

podrias recorrer los `<input>` que se encuentran dentro de tu `<form>` y así poder verificar si tienen información para deshabilitarlos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                
             var paterno= 'Mendez';
             var materno= '';
             var nombre= 'Juan'

             $('#epaterno').val(paterno);
             $('#ematerno').val(materno);
             $('#enombre').val(nombre);

                $("#formDatos input").each(function (element) {
                    if ($(this).val() != "") {
                        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="update.php" method="POST" id="formDatos">
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Paterno:</span>
                <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="epaterno" id="epaterno" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Materno:</span>
                <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="ematerno" id="ematerno">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Nombre:</span>
                <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="enombre" id="enombre" >
            </div>
    </body>
    </body>

</html>
```

Saludos.

Comment: es excelente.... solo que al modal le envio los datos con jquery, es decir, en los values no tengo nada... como seria?

Comment: Hola, me imagino que esta usando los modal con JQuery y antes del que el modal se abra pones los datos en el input, despues de esto puedes poner el for para que habilite o deshabilites los input, si pudieras compartir un poco del código para tener una idea mas clara y así poder ayudarte mejor seria genial.

Comment: asi es... es exactamente lo que hago ya puse el codigo js con el q lo hago, encontre una funcion que lee el value, pero digamos que yo lo tengo vacio

Comment: Edite la respuesta, creo que es a lo que te refieres, ya no tiene la propiedad value el input si no que asigna el valor JQuery.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos ya funciona excelente!!